# Filter result set of a CTE based on a computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the columns which appeared in more than one table in a given database. I have succeeded in coming up a result set which is giving column name, table name and additional rank column and a flag (0 or 1) for more than one occurrence.

I am just wondering if its possible to filter this CTE based on last column

```
;with CTE as
(
    SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c.name order by c.name) as NumberofOcuurance
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id    
)    
select *, 
    case
    when    LEAD(NumberofOcuurance,1) over (order by colName) = NumberofOcuurance then  0
    when    LEAD(NumberofOcuurance,1) over (order by colName) <> NumberofOcuurance then  1
    End as Morethan1    
from CTE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a sub-query/derived table e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.[name] AS ColName, t.[name] AS TableName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.[name] ORDER BY c.[name]) AS NumberofOccurrance
    FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * 
        , CASE
        WHEN LEAD(NumberofOccurrance, 1) OVER (ORDER BY colName) = NumberofOccurrance THEN 0
        WHEN LEAD(NumberofOccurrance, 1) OVER (ORDER BY colName) <> NumberofOccurrance THEN 1
        END AS Morethan1
    FROM cte 
) x
WHERE x.Morethan1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `information_schema` views?

```
select column_name, string_agg(table_name, ',') as table_names
from information_schema.columns
group by column_name
having count(*) > 1
```